# python, default parameters/arguments for builtin open?

Tags: python

Right, simple question here. I couldn't find an answer using google and looking here.

I need to write a few stubs for builtin functions within python like `open(name[, mode[, buffering]])`. However I can't seem to find the default values for `mode` and `buffering`
It does not seem to be `None`

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Comment: It only says they are optional, but not stating their defaults? Or am I just reading over it?

Comment: nevermind. Guess I am becoming blind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making wrappers for the built-ins, what you usually end up doing is something like:

```
def myOpen(name, mode='r', buffer=None):
    if buffer:
        open_file = open(name, mode, buffer)
    else:
        open_file = open(name, mode)
```

The reason is that not all the arguments are accesible via keyword (`buffer` in this case).

Comment: I would personally do it this way in that case: `open(*([name, mode, buffering] if buffering != None else [name, mode]))` (I am not good with one-liners with woman, but python goes well though) good tip btw!

Comment: Why don't you just do `def myOpen(name, mode='r', *args, **kwargs): return open(name, mode, *args, **kwargs)`? Which, in fact, is pointless ;) Default for `mode` is `'r'`, and buffer can always be set explicitly to avoid system default.

Comment: @Tadeck, because `--> myopen('/temp/test.py', buffer=1024)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in myopen
TypeError: 'buffer' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`  -- in other words, `buffer` is not supported as a keyword argument.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation of `open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

> If **`mode`** is omitted, it **defaults to `'r'`**.
>
> ...
>
> The optional **`buffering`** argument specifies the file’s desired buffer size (...) If omitted, the **system default is used**.

When it comes to the system default for `buffering`:

> Specifying a buffer size currently has no effect on systems that don’t have `setvbuf()`. The interface to specify the buffer size is not done using a method that calls `setvbuf()`, because that may dump core when called after any I/O has been performed, and there’s no reliable way to determine whether this is the case.

Comment: Bah! Guess I am becoming blind :-/ Any clue how to get the 'systems default' for `buffering` ?

Comment: guess I'll just not stub that specific parameter then. Cheers for copying the python docs and highlighting specified parts :-)

Comment: @DaanTimmer: In this case it would be hard to answer it better than the official documentation ;)

Comment: hence thanks for highlighting the parts that I obviously did not see!